# Why is ng-maxlength not re-evaluated?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a form, that has one input field and three check boxes. Depending on which check box is selected the max length on the field needs to change. I have a input field defined like this

```
 <input placeholder="ID" type="text" id="form_ID" name="searchId" autofocus
 data-ng-model="vm.searchCriteria.searchId" data-ng-required="vm.isSearchIdRequired"
 data-ng-minlength="1" data-ng-maxlength="{{searchIdMaxLength}}"
 data-ng-class="{'input-error': vm.isSearchIdValid}">
```

and one of the checkboxes

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" class="hidden-field"
  data-ng-model="vm.searchCriteria.searchIdInSrId" data-ng-checked="vm.searchCriteria.searchIdInSrId"
 data-ng-change="processSearchIdOptionsChange()">
```

So everytime user changes which checkbox is/are selected  `processSearchIdOptionsChange` gets called, and `searchIdMaxLength` changes it's value. This is all working fine and I can see the value being changed on the $scope. But, my initial max length is still being applied. Following error pops up after initial max number of chars is reached. Why?

```
<span class="error" data-ng-show="(searchForm.$dirty &&  searchForm.searchId.$error.maxlength)">Too long!</span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error here is the directive that does what I need. Please if you have any suggestions or improvements share them, I have only 7 days of angular under my belt, and javascript is something that i have a cursory knowledge of.

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('commonModule')
        .directive('srMaxlength', ['$window', srMaxlength]);

    function srMaxlength($window) {
        // Usage:
        // use if you need to switch max length validation dynamically based on
        // Creates:
        // removes old validator for max length and creates new one 
        var directive = {
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: link,
            restrict: 'A'
        };

        return directive;

        function link(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            attrs.$observe("srMaxlength", function (newval) {
                var maxlength = parseInt(newval, 10);
                var name = "srMaxLengthValidator";

                for (var i = ctrl.$parsers.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    if (ctrl.$parsers[i].name !== undefined && ctrl.$parsers[i].name == name) {
                        ctrl.$parsers.splice(i, 1);
                    }
                }

                for (var j = ctrl.$formatters.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                    if (ctrl.$formatters[j].name !== undefined && ctrl.$formatters[j].name == name) {
                        ctrl.$formatters.splice(j, 1);
                    }
                }

                ctrl.$parsers.push(maxLengthValidator);
                ctrl.$formatters.push(maxLengthValidator);

                //name the function so we can find it always by the name
                maxLengthValidator.name = name;

                function maxLengthValidator(value) {
                    if (!ctrl.$isEmpty(value) && value.length > maxlength) {
                        ctrl.$setValidity('maxlength', false);
                        return undefined;
                    } else {
                        ctrl.$setValidity('maxlength', true);
                        return value;
                    }
                } 
            });
        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: This almost works; maxLengthValidator() should ``return value;`` in either case, or validation error messages are not properly reported using ``FORM.COMPONENTNAME.$error.minlength``

Comment: @TimBoudreau: You mean maxlength?

Answer (score 2):

This is the intended behaviour of ng-maxlength. Verified from source : https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/input.js?source=c#L523

The value is parsed only once and cached :

```
 var maxlength = int(attr.ngMaxlength);
```

If you want to observe the change you need to create your own directive which uses something like

```
scope.$watch(attr.namespaceMaxLength,function(){
// clear old validator. Add new one. 
})
```

Comment: Went to angularjs.org and looked for documentation on $watch, and could not find anything :(

Comment: `$watch`is a method available on [`$scope` type](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#methods_$watch).

Comment: @basarat: If I understand this correctly, I would remove validator from the ctrl.$parsers and ctrl.$formatters and re-add with a new max length. Would I also need to call $scope.apply ?

Comment: @epitka "I would remove validator from the ctrl.$parsers and ctrl.$formatters and re-add with a new max length." yes, "Would I also need to call $scope.apply " no. a watch is executed within a digest loop so scope.$apply would actually throw an error.

Comment: @basarat: Could you please provide an example fiddle to see your recommended approach.